# Does Azure E2s_v3 virtual machine size support accelerated networking?

Tags: azure, performance, azure-virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I have a `B4ms` Azure virtual machine whose performance and Remote Desktop experience is not too impressive. I then looked into enabling accelerated networking to improve those two attributes.

I therefore followed the instructions [in the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-cli#enable-accelerated-networking-on-existing-vms) on enabling accelerated networking for an existing VM. On the last step, an error came up stating that my `B4ms` does not support AN.

I have searched online to find what VM sizes support AN, and have only come across this one [here](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2018/01/05/accelerated-networking-for-azure-vms.aspx?m=1) but it seems the list has names that are not in use anymore (I did a search in Azure). I am not familiar with the nomenclature so I may be missing something in the naming.

I can't find any documentation on the specs for each of these sizes from Azure.

Would anyone know if `E2s_v3` supports AN?

Comment: It shows in the [Limitations and Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-cli#limitations-and-constraints). E/ESv3 supports hyperthreading. Accelerated Networking is supported on VM instances with 4 or more vCPUs.

Comment: @CharlesXu I initially had `B4ms` which has 4 vCPUs, but that said it does not support AN...

Comment: @CharlesXu I just checked, seems like it further goes down to certain series: `D/DSv2` and `F/Fs` for 2 cores, and `D/DSv3`, `E/ESv3`, `Fsv2`,  `Ms/Mms` for 4 cores. I had E2s_v3 with 2 cores, so no support. Thanks for that link.

Comment: It also shows in it. Accelerated Networking just supports the size D/DSv2 and F/Fs, D/DSv3, E/ESv3, Fsv2, and Ms/Mms. And another limitation with some of them.

Comment: OK, you can add it to your answer without showing all the size. Or I could do it for you, then you can mark it. All depends on you.

Comment: @CharlesXu Add yours as an answer. Stating the series and their cores is the shorter precise answer. Post that and ill mark as correct answer. That link in itself us very useful. Please include. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Accelerated Networking in Azure, it just supports the size series D/DSv2 and F/Fs, D/DSv3, E/ESv3, Fsv2, and Ms/Mms. And there also another limitation with some of them.

For size series D/DSv2 and F/Fs, it supports the instances with 2 or more vCPUs. For size series D/DSv3, E/ESv3, Fsv2, and Ms/Mms, it just supports the instances with 4 or more vCPUs, not all the size.

And another point you also should pay attention to.

> VMs with Accelerated Networking enabled can only be resized to VMs
>   that support Accelerated Networking. And the VM without accelerated networking just can be enabled in the stopped and deallocated state.

See the [Limitations and Constraints of Accelerated Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-cli#limitations-and-constraints) to get more details.

Answer (score 1):

No, E2s_v3 does not support accelerated networking. In the E series only the 4 vCPU sizes support AN eg E4s_v3.

---

I ran the command: `az network nic update --name myAzureVMName --resource-group MY_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --accelerated-networking true` on my VM which I had resized to `E2s_v3` first. I got the error again stating that it does not support it. There is actually a list of supporting sizes. See screenshot:

[image]

**Here is the extracted list of sizes that support Accelerated Networking (for standard VMs):**

`AZAP_Performance_ComputeV17C, AZAP_Performance_ComputeV17C_DDA,
 Experimental_E64-40s_v3,
 SQLGL, SQLGLCore,
 StStandard_F8andard_DS14-8_v2, 
 Standard_D11_v2, Standard_D11_v2_Promo,
 Standard_D12_v2, Standard_D12_v2_ABC, Standard_D12_v2_Promo,
 Standard_D13_v2, Standard_D13_v2_ABC,Standard_D13_v2_Promo,
 Standard_D14_v2,Standard_D14_v2_ABC, Standard_D14_v2_Promo,
 Standard_D15_v2,Standard_D15_v2_ABC, Standard_D15_v2_Nested, Standard_D15_v2_Promo,
 Standard_D16_v3, Standard_D16s_v3,
 Standard_D2_v2, Standard_D2_v2_Promo,
 Standard_D32-16s_v3, Standard_D32-8s_v3,Standard_D32_v3, Standard_D32s_v3,
 Standard_D3_v2, Standard_D3_v2_ABC, Standard_D3_v2_Promo,
 Standard_D40_v3, Standard_D40s_v3,
 Standard_D4_v2, Standard_D4_v2_ABC, Standard_D4_v2_Promo, Standard_D4_v3, Standard_D4s_v3,
 Standard_D5_v2, Standard_D5_v2_ABC, Standard_D5_v2_Promo,
 Standard_D64-16s_v3, Standard_D64-32s_v3, Standard_D64_v3, Standard_D64s_v3,
 Standard_D8_v3, Standard_D8s_v3,
 Standard_DS11-1_v2, Standard_DS11_v2, Standard_DS11_v2_Promo,
 Standard_DS12-1_v2, Standard_DS12-2_v2, Standard_DS12_v2, Standard_DS12_v2_Promo,
 Standard_DS13-2_v2, Standard_DS13-4_v2, Standard_DS13-4_v2_Promo, Standard_DS13_v2, Standard_DS13_v2_Promo,
 Standard_DS14-4_v2, Standard_DS14-4_v2_Promo, Standard_DS14-8_v2_Promo, Standard_DS14_v2, Standard_DS14_v2_Promo,
 Standard_DS15_v2, Standard_DS15_v2_Nested, Standard_DS15_v2_Promo,
 Standard_DS2_v2, Standard_DS2_v2_Promo,
 Standard_DS3_v2, Standard_DS3_v2_Promo,
 Standard_DS4_v2, Standard_DS4_v2_Promo,
 Standard_DS5_v2, Standard_DS5_v2_Promo,
 Standard_E16-4s_v3, Standard_E16-8s_v3, Standard_E16_v3, Standard_E16s_v3,
 Standard_E20_v3, Standard_E20s_v3,
 Standard_E32-16_v3, Standard_E32-16s_v3, Standard_E32-8s_v3, Standard_E32_v3, Standard_E32s_v3,
 Standard_E4-2s_v3, Standard_E4_v3, Standard_E4s_v3,
 Standard_E64-16s_v3, Standard_E64-32s_v3, Standard_E64_v3,
 Standard_E64i_v3, Standard_E64is_v3, Standard_E64s_v3,
 Standard_E8-2s_v3, Standard_E8-4s_v3, Standard_E8_v3, Standard_E8s_v3,
 Standard_F16, Standard_F16_ABC, Standard_F16s, Standard_F16s_v2,
 Standard_F2, Standard_F2s,
 Standard_F32s_v2,
 Standard_F4, Standard_F4_ABC, Standard_F4s, Standard_F4s_v2,
 Standard_F64s_v2,
 Standard_F72s_v2,
 Standard_F8_ABC, Standard_F8s, Standard_F8s_v2,
 Standard_L16s_v2, Standard_L32s_v2, Standard_L64s_v2, Standard_L80s_v2, Standard_L8s_v2,
 Standard_M128-32ms, Standard_M128-64ms, Standard_M128ms, Standard_M128s,
 Standard_M16-4ms, Standard_M16-8ms, Standard_M16ms,
 Standard_M208ms_v2,
 Standard_M32-16ms, Standard_M32-8ms, Standard_M32ls, Standard_M32ms, Standard_M32ts,
 Standard_M64-16ms, Standard_M64-32ms, Standard_M64ls, Standard_M64ms, Standard_M64s,
 Standard_M8-2ms, Standard_M8-4ms, Standard_M8ms,
 Standard_MDB16s, Standard_MDB32s,
 Standard_PB12s, Standard_PB24s, Standard_PB6s,`